# Is there any way to convert fraction to percentage without converting to decimal?

Tags: fractions, percentages

I know that you can convert fraction to percentage without converting to decimal.

Ex:

2/5 =  2/5 * 20/20 = 40%

How about fractions with denominator that cannot be converted to 100

Ex: 2/13

Is there any way / formula to solve this without converting the fraction to decimal?

Comment: (2/13)*100% = (200/13)% = (195 + 5)/13 = 15% + (5/13)%

Comment: Can you ask your calculator? A calculator says $\frac{2}{13}\approx 15.38~\%$

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Note that $40\%$ simply means $\dfrac{40}{100}$. So, can you write $\dfrac2{13}$ as $\dfrac k{100}$ for some integer $k$? No, because$$\frac2{13}=\frac k{100}\iff200=13k.$$But $200$ is not a multiple of $13$.

Comment: So i have to convert the fraction to decimal first just to get the percentage?

Comment: Yes, you do. But it will always be an approximation.

Comment: Ok thanks , i thought there's a much faster way to convert.

Comment: @Franz there is. break the numerator into 2 numbers, one should be the multiple of the divisor. For example, 100/24 can be written as (96 + 4)/24 = (4 + 4/24). Similarly, the above is divided 200/13% = (195+5)/13 = (15 + 5/13)%

Comment: @arnav007 but i still have to convert 5/13 which will make me need more time to solve?

Comment: @Franz in most of the questions, the solution will remain as a fraction.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a fraction to a percentage, simply change the denominator to $100.$ To do this, multiply by $1=100/100=100\%,$ which does not change anything.

Thus, for example, we have that $$2/13=2/13×100\%=200/13\%=15\frac{5}{13}\%.$$

Comment: Thanks , but i'm finding a much easier/faster way to convert

Comment: @Franz There's no regal road.